# How to disable "Do you want to sign in to * with your Apple ID" modal in Safari?

Tags: apple-id, touch-id

I am a consultant, so I have my Mac logged in to my personal Apple ID, but during the day, I log with Safari to various Apple websites with my **multiple work-related Apple IDs**.

I would like to disable a modal which comes with a Touch ID (or login password), because it's rather slow - it takes, on a M1 Pro, ca 6 to 15 seconds to load. I always need to wait, then click either Cancel or Use a Different Apple ID, and then I can log in with my work email.

Any idea how to do that? Nothing seems to be in the Develop menu, and no hits about a nice `defaults` either...

Yes, you could suggest "don't use Safari" - but then I would have to retype the SMS code I get almost every time I log in, while Safari fills it automagically...

[image: Do you want to sign in modal]

Also, sometimes the modal gets stuck, and it stays like this. Sometimes it's possible to press Esc or do a Touch ID to log in to my personal A-ID, but otherwise the whole Safari is stuck, I had to force-quit it so I could continue with my work. Quitting Safari usually cures the stuck modal.

[image: Modal stuck]

**Update**: I found out I can kill the modal with this command:

```
killall -QUIT AKAppSSOExtension_macOS
```

Then, I created a Shortcut with **Run Shell Script** action and pinned it to my menu bar so I could run it when I need it. Still, I would prefer a preference where I could disable it entirely.

[image: Shortcut app setup]

So I guess, the question now became more general: is there a proper way how to keep `AKAppSSOExtension_macOS` loading completely? There are preference files such as

`/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.AppSSOAgent.plist`

but these are on a read-only partitions, right?

Comment: Strange - for me it loads within 5 seconds. Nevertheless, it is annoying.

Comment: Well. Between 5 and 6 seconds on a good day. I don’t think internet speed is a factor, I have 250mbps download, but sometimes the modal itself animates very slowly, like it was a 10yo intel with HD and full ram. Yet it’s a 16 GB M1 Pro. When the modal gets stuck, restarting Safari helps. But the main point is -  in a week, I need once to go to my iCloud, but 50+ times to go in with other Apple ID. I have a feeling some iOS developers (contractors for corporations) would have the same issue.

Comment: I just tested on appleid.apple.com and after clicking "Sign In" the dialog appears with a clickable "Use a different Apple ID" button in < 3 seconds. Perhaps your work VPN (if you have one) is causing a delay while it tries to establish the right connection.

Comment: Yeah. If I do it now, it also shows relatively quickly. Again - if you need, once a while, to go to there to mostly maintain your main AID, it's ok. But if you have to do it something like ten times a day for different AIDs, you would start to be annoyed by it. Especially if it starts to get stuck, as shown in an above screenshot. Sometimes the only way to literally un-stuck your *whole* Safari is to touch-id to unwanted AID and close the window, hoping the next time it will be better. Also, no VPN, 250mbps line, or 1200mbps 5G, fast M1, doesn't matter, still gets stuck or slow often.